# Are Pakistani citizens allowed to enter Goa, India?

Tags: india, pakistani-citizens

Are there any kind of restrictions on Pakistani Nationals to enter in Goa, India, for any reason?

If so, what are the restrictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not as far as I can tell**.  As I'm sure you're aware, the visa application process for Pakistani nationals visiting India is lengthy and painful, but the [High Commission of India in Islamabad](http://www.india.org.pk/pak-visitors-visa.html)'s site only notes that "*Prohibited/Restricted/Cantonment Areas*" are off-limits.  RAP/PAPs are listed [here](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/protected-restricted-area-permit-india.html), and while eg. much of the north-east and Kashmir are on the list, Goa is not.  [Cantonments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonment#India) refers to the military quarters scattered around India's cities and a tourist wouldn't have business there anyway.

Comment: well apart from other process which i know is hard, Does it mean Goa does not have any restriction like Kashmir ?

Comment: It's definitely not a restricted area like Kashmir, and I can't find any other written restrictions about it.